# "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values" while retrieving data - EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is a migration project, I have a table in SQL Server containing image data stored as `VARBINARY(MAX)` data type, able to store image as `byte[]` to database using EF Core 8. While retrieving data from database using EF Core, I get an exception.

Database table schema:

[image]

DbSet model

[image]

Rows in the database, inserted using same EF Core `DbContext`:

[image]

But while retrieving collection of rows using the code shown here, it is throwing an exception

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Code:

```
var dbContext = new MigrationDBContext();
var list = dbContext.ImageDetails.ToList();
```

I am trying storing image data with EF Core for the very first time, any suggestions?

Comment: `File_Blob_Path` and `File_Local_Path` should be of type `string?`. And do not post code as images.

Comment: thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv, this really helped to solve the problem.